# Appending Map Iteration Index to Original Input of Step Function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a step function step, where I use a map to iterate through an array of elements, invoking a service. I need the service to know which iteration it is processing. I want to do this by adding the index of the map iteration to the original input (as service cannot be updated to process changes to the input).

Below is what I tried:

```
const appendIterationPass = new sfn.Pass(this, 'Append Iteration', {
      parameters: {
           'originalInput.$': '$',
           'executionIteration.$': '$$.Map.Item.Index'
      },
      resultPath: '$'
 });

 const myExecutor = new sfn.Map(this, 'MyExecutor', {
     outputPath: '$',
      itemsPath: '$',
 });

 myExecutor.iterator(appendIterationPass.next(preprocess));
 myExecutor.addCatch(tranformExecutionFailureResult, {
     errors: ['States.ALL'],
     resultPath: '$[0].error'
 });
```

But at the step function execution, I'm getting this exception as soon as the step appendIteration is entered:

```
An error occurred while executing the state 'Append Iteration' (entered at the event id #29). The JSONPath '$$.Map.Item.Index' specified for the field 'executionIteration.$' could not be found in the input
```

How can I get the iteration index and append it to the original input that my service gets? Appreciate any guidance/advice.